# texdoc doesn’t search at $TEXMFHOME

Tags: texdoc

I built a little private package and I want `texdoc` to find its manual. So I moved the documentation to `<TEXMFHOME>/doc/twindex.pdf` (i.e. `~/Library/texmf/doc/twindex.pdf` on my Mac). But if I call

```
texdoc twindex
```

it doesn’t find the package. If I ask `kpsewhich` with

```
kpsewhich -format "TeX system documentation" twindex.pdf
```

it finds the right file (`/Users/Tobi/Library/texmf/doc/twindex.pdf`)

I thought that `texdoc` looks at `$TEXMFHOME` too, am I wrong with that? How can I configure it to search there too?

### Update

<sup>Belonging to Andrey’s (and Phil’s) answer</sup>

I tried to use a category but it doesn’t work. `kpsewhich` finds the file at

```
/Users/Tobi/Library/texmf/doc/latex/twindex/twindex.pdf
```

I also had a look at `$TEXDOCS` and it contains my `texmf` folder. But if I compare it with `$PATH`, there is a difference. In the latter the paths are separated by `:` instead of `,` may this the problem?

### Update 2

The `TEXDOCS` varaiable contains my user texmf folder (line 3):

```
Tobis-Mac:~ Tobi$ kpsewhich --var-value TEXDOCS
{/Users/Tobi/Library/texlive/2011/texmf-config,
/Users/Tobi/Library/texlive/2011/texmf-var,
/Users/Tobi/Library/texmf,
!!/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-config,
!!/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-var,
!!/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf,
!!/usr/local/texlive/2011/../texmf-local,
!!/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist}/doc//
```

### Update 3

To debug `texdoc` I tried `texdoc --debug=texdocs twindex` while twindex.pdf is saved at `$TEXMFHOME/doc/latex/twindex/twindex.pdf` *and* additionally at `$TEXMFHOME/tex/latex /tw/twindex/twindex.pdf` and `$TEXMFHOME/twindex.pdf` my home path is `$TEXMFOME` = `/Users/Tobi/Library/texmf`

```
Tobis-Mac:texmf Tobi$ texdoc --debug=texdocs twindex
texdoc debug-version: /usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf/scripts/texdoc/texdoclib.tlu version 0.83
texdoc debug-texdocs: texdocs[8] = /Users/Tobi/Library/texlive/2011/texmf-config/doc (index_mandatory=false, recursion_allowed=true)
texdoc debug-texdocs: texdocs[7] = /Users/Tobi/Library/texlive/2011/texmf-var/doc (index_mandatory=false, recursion_allowed=true)
texdoc debug-texdocs: texdocs[6] = /Users/Tobi/Library/texmf/doc (index_mandatory=false, recursion_allowed=true)
texdoc debug-texdocs: texdocs[6] using index: /Users/Tobi/Library/texmf (shift=doc/)
texdoc debug-texdocs: texdocs[5] = /usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-config/doc (index_mandatory=true, recursion_allowed=true)
texdoc debug-texdocs: texdocs[4] = /usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-var/doc (index_mandatory=true, recursion_allowed=true)
texdoc debug-texdocs: texdocs[3] = /usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf/doc (index_mandatory=true, recursion_allowed=true)
texdoc debug-texdocs: texdocs[3] using index: /usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf (shift=doc/)
texdoc debug-texdocs: texdocs[2] = /usr/local/texlive/2011/../texmf-local/doc (index_mandatory=true, recursion_allowed=true)
texdoc debug-texdocs: texdocs[1] = /usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/doc (index_mandatory=true, recursion_allowed=true)
texdoc debug-texdocs: texdocs[1] using index: /usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist (shift=doc/)
Sorry, no documentation found for twindex.
If you are unsure about the name, try searching CTAN's TeX catalogue at
http://ctan.org/search.html#byDescription.
```

Everything seems ok. As far as I can see `texdoc` searches `/Users/Tobi/Library/texmf/doc` recursive which includes the `twindex` path …

I have to correct myself, `twindex is not found at`$TEXMFHOME/twindex.pdf` too.

If I call `ls -R` in `texmf` the list contains all three places of `twindex.pdf`.

Whats wrong with my system?

Comment: I believe Andrey Vihrov's answer is the correct one. But just for information, texdoc 0.83 appears to find documents even without the `<category>` component. Which version of texdoc are you using (`texdoc --version`)?

Comment: @mpg: I’m using 0.83. But Andrey’s answer doesn’t work …

Comment: @Tobi: Try `texdoc -d -v twindex` and see if there is something relevant.

Comment: @AndreyVihrov: Can’˝ see anything that help one o the lines is still `Sorry, no documentation found for twindex` :-(

Comment: @Tobi `TEXDOCS` is a "virtual" environment variable that in general you don't set. In order to see its value (which is known to the TeX programs), do `kpsewhich --var-value TEXDOCS`. The fact that this has a comma separated list as value, compared to `$PATH`, where the value is a colon separated list, is irrelevant.

Comment: @egreg: I checked the variable (see my edit) and it contains my user texmf folder, but `texdoc` doesn’t find the manuals.

Comment: It would help if you show the output of `kpsewhich --var-value TEXDOCS` (mask the part identifying your home directory, if you wish), after making sure the variable is *not* set in the environment (`unset TEXDOCS`)

Comment: @egreg: See the output above. There’s no difference if saying `unset TEXDOCS` before.

Comment: The output is regular. The `//` is automatically added as it is at the end, so it's applied at everything in the braced group.

Comment: Then there’s something worn on my system. Why does `textdoc` find the manual `Tobi/Library/texmf/manual.pdf` but not `Tobi/Library/texmf/text/latex/<package>/manual.pdf` if it searches recursively?

Comment: Stupid question: Did you update the `ls-R`-database for `$TEXMFHOME`? This isn't needed for `kpathsea` (it'll search the whole directory structure as there is no `!!` in front of `/Users/Tobi/Library/texmf`), but `texdoc` relies on the database. You can check the file `/Users/Tobi/Library/texmf/ls-R` for the appearance of your manual `twindex.pdf`.

Comment: @diabonas: No I didn’t but if one is required `texdoc` shouldn’t find `/Users/Tobi/Library/texmf/twindex.pdf` too … which it actually does.

Comment: Yeah, you're probably right, I overlooked that. On the other hand, according to your `$TEXDOCS` variable, `texdoc` shouldn't look into the root of `$TEXMFHOME` at all (only [recursively] into its subdirectory `/doc`). In fact, if I put a PDF file in my `$TEXMFHOME`, it isn't found by `texdoc`, regardless of updating the database.

Comment: @diabonas: Is there a place in your `$TEXMFHOME` where `texdoc` find’s the PDF?

Comment: The PDF document is only found by `texdoc` if I put it in the `/doc` directory or one of its subdirectories. The other directories of `$TEXMFHOME` or `$TEXMFHOME` itself don't work. To expand a bit on the `ls-R`-database: `texdoc` doesn't seem to require it for `$TEXMFHOME`, but it uses it if it's present, therefore ignoring files which are in the file system, but not in the database.

Comment: @Tobi: I have XyMTeX in my TEXMFHOME and `texdoc xymtex` works flawlessly out of the box. It is in `~/Library/texmf/doc/latex/xymtex/doc101`.

Comment: Regarding your third update: Did you call the *command* `ls -R` or did you check the `ls-R` *file*  `/Users/Tobi/Library/texmf/ls-R`? The debug output states that the latter is used by `texdoc`, so it has to be up-to-date so that the PDF document is found. Try updating it with `mktexlsr /Users/Tobi/Library/texmf` or delete it altogether (it isn't required by `kpathsea` or `texdoc`).

Comment: @diabonas: That’s it, thanks. The update helped to make `texdoc` find the files :-). Do I have to do the update form time to time or can i delete the `ls-R` file without trouble? [If you post your comments as an answer I could accept them.]

Comment: You can safely delete the `ls-R` file, it isn't needed (`$TEXMFHOME` doesn't contain that many files in most cases, so it won't take much longer to search it directly). In fact, in my opinion it is better not to have it as one might forget to update it - it isn't included in normal `mktexlsr` runs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`texdoc` doesn't call `kpathsea` directly to find the documentation files. Instead, it uses the `$TEXDOCS` variable, expands it with the help of `kpathsea` and browses the directories for documentation files by itself. This yields essentially the same results as a direct call of

```
kpsewhich -path=$TEXDOCS twindex.pdf
```

*However, there is one important difference:* If **`kpathsea`** encounters a directory where no `ls-R` database is required (i. e. a directory with no `!!` prefix in the path specification), it searchs the whole file system, regardless of whether there is a `ls-R` database for it or not. **`texdoc`**, however, relies on that database if present, so if a file is not in the database, it isn't found even if it is in the file system.

So I suspect your `ls-R` database for `$TEXMFHOME` is out of date. Try updating it using

```
mktexlsr /Users/Tobi/Library/texmf
```

(you have to specify the path manually as `$TEXMFHOME` isn't in `$TEXMFDBS`). Another possibility is to delete the file

```
/Users/Tobi/Library/texmf/ls-R
```

altogether, as a database file isn't required by either `kpathsea` or `texdoc` - like this, `texdoc` will access the file system directly.

Comment: Thanks again! I removed the `ls-R` file and everything is fine now. But can I configure `$TEXDOCS` in a way that the documentations are found if they are not in the `doc/` tree but in `tex/latex/…`? I guess I have to change the variable, but how?

Comment: @Tobi The variable can be changed in the configuration file `$TEXMFROOT/texmf.cnf`: Either by directly adding the line `TEXDOCS = $TEXMF/doc//,$TEXMFHOME/tex/latex//` or by using `tlmgr` to do that: `tlmgr conf texmf TEXDOCS $TEXMF/doc//,$TEXMFHOME/tex/latex//`

Comment: If I call the `tlmgr` the new paths will be appended to the exiting ones, right?

Comment: @Tobi `tlmgr` essentially adds the line to `$TEXMF/texmf.cnf`, which will override the existing path. That means both solutions require you to specify the complete path - I don't know whether it's possible to append new directories while keeping the existing ones.

Comment: Your welcome! Thanks for solving my problem ;-)

Answer (score 9):

As per [TDS specification](http://ctan.org/pkg/tds), the path should resemble those for the `tex` and `fonts` directories and be

```
texmf/doc/<category>/...
```

where

> *category* identifies the general topic of documentation that resides below it; for example, a TeX format name (`latex`), program name
>   (`bibtex`, `tex`), language (`french`, `german`), a file format
>   (`info`, `man`), or other system components (`web`, `fonts`).

Therefore, assuming that your package is designed for LaTeX, place its documentation in the directory

```
texmf/doc/latex/<your package>
```

Comment: Sounds good but doesn’t help either. Please see my question edit.

Answer (score 2):

The full details of where texdoc looks are given in the texdoc manual, `texdoc.pdf`, (say `texdoc texdoc` in your Terminal). Roughly, it looks in trees given by `$TEXDOCS` given by

```
kpsewhich --var TEXDOCS
```

In my case this includes `~/Library/texmf` but not `~/Library/texmf/doc` — it also includes lots of other places so best to check out the detail

Comment: It does looks into `TEXMFHOME/doc` for at least two reasons: 1. `TEXMFHOME` is part of a brace-expression that ends with `/doc` so `/doc` is appended to each component, and 2. the expression actually ends with `//` which means to search recursively. Try `texdoc kpathsea` for details :)

Comment: Could you pleas post your full `TEXDOCS` variable so I can compare it with mine?

Answer (score 2):

You can debug the paths used by `texdoc` calling it by

```
texdoc --debug=texdocs twindex
```

Using a document I have as `~/Library/texmf/doc/latex/xymtex/doc101/xymtex.pdf` calling

```
texdoc --debug=texdocs xymtex
```

gives

```
texdoc debug-version: /usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf/scripts/texdoc/texdoclib.tlu version 0.83
texdoc debug-texdocs: texdocs[8] = ~/Library/texlive/2011/texmf-config/doc (index_mandatory=false, recursion_allowed=true)
texdoc debug-texdocs: texdocs[7] = ~/Library/texlive/2011/texmf-var/doc (index_mandatory=false, recursion_allowed=true)
texdoc debug-texdocs: texdocs[6] = ~/Library/texmf/doc (index_mandatory=false, recursion_allowed=true)
texdoc debug-texdocs: texdocs[6] using filesystem search
texdoc debug-texdocs: texdocs[5] = /usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-config/doc (index_mandatory=true, recursion_allowed=true)
texdoc debug-texdocs: texdocs[4] = /usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-var/doc (index_mandatory=true, recursion_allowed=true)
texdoc debug-texdocs: texdocs[3] = /usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf/doc (index_mandatory=true, recursion_allowed=true)
texdoc debug-texdocs: texdocs[3] using index: /usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf (shift=doc/)
texdoc debug-texdocs: texdocs[2] = /usr/local/texlive/2011/../texmf-local/doc (index_mandatory=true, recursion_allowed=true)
texdoc debug-texdocs: texdocs[2] using index: /usr/local/texlive/2011/../texmf-local (shift=doc/)
texdoc debug-texdocs: texdocs[1] = /usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/doc (index_mandatory=true, recursion_allowed=true)
texdoc debug-texdocs: texdocs[1] using index: /usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist (shift=doc/)
```

Note: I've masked with `~` the real root of my home in the output.

Comment: I put the output to my question …