# texdoc does not work anymore after Ubuntu upgrade

Tags: texlive, ubuntu, texdoc

Since i upgraded my Ubuntu system to 18.04, `texdoc` fails to find anything.

In the process of my experiments, trying to make it work, the symptoms changes: first it complained that it could not find some PDF file, and the file indeed was not there, but then i installed (or reinstalled, i do not remember) the package with the missing file, and now `texdoc` replies to everything with "Sorry, no documentation found for ...":

```
§ texdoc algorithmicx
Sorry, no documentation found for algorithmicx.
If you are unsure about the name, try searching CTAN's TeX catalogue at
http://ctan.org/search.html#byDescription.
```

```
§ ls /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/doc/latex/algorithmicx/
algorithmicx.pdf  algorithmicx.tex.gz  README
```

```
§ apt list "texlive-science*"
Listing... Done
texlive-science/bionic,bionic,now 2017.20180305-2 all [installed]
texlive-science-doc/bionic,bionic,now 2017.20180305-2 all [installed]
```

```
§ texdoc -d algorithmicx
texdoc debug-version: /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/scripts/texdoc/texdoclib.tlu version 2.0171
texdoc debug-config: Setting 'debug_list=all' from command line option "-d".
texdoc debug-config: Setting 'viewer_pdf=(xdg-open %s) &' in file "/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/texdoc/texdoc.cnf" on line 37.
texdoc debug-config: Setting 'viewer_ps=(xdg-open %s) &' in file "/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/texdoc/texdoc.cnf" on line 38.
texdoc debug-config: Setting 'viewer_dvi=(xdg-open %s) &' in file "/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/texdoc/texdoc.cnf" on line 39.
texdoc debug-config: Setting 'viewer_html=(xdg-open %s) &' in file "/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/texdoc/texdoc.cnf" on line 40.
texdoc debug-config: Setting 'viewer_txt=(xdg-open %s) &' in file "/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/texdoc/texdoc.cnf" on line 41.
texdoc debug-config: Setting 'zipext_list=gz, bz2, xz' in file "/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/texdoc/texdoc.cnf" on line 70.
texdoc debug-config: Setting 'unzip_gz=gzip -d -c' in file "/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/texdoc/texdoc.cnf" on line 71.
texdoc debug-config: Setting 'unzip_bz2=bzip2 -d -c' in file "/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/texdoc/texdoc.cnf" on line 72.
texdoc debug-config: Setting 'unzip_xz=xz --decompress --stdout' in file "/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/texdoc/texdoc.cnf" on line 73.
texdoc debug-config: Setting 'suffix_list=doc, -doc, _doc, .doc, /doc, manual, /manual, -manual, userguide, /user_guide, -guide, -user, -man, notes, -info, ref' in file "/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/texdoc/texdoc.cnf" on line 98.
texdoc debug-config: Setting 'lastfile_switch=true' in file "/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/texdoc/texdoc.cnf" on line 502.
texdoc debug-config: Setting 'lang=en' from operating system locale.
texdoc debug-config: Setting 'badext_list=txt, ' from built-in defaults.
texdoc debug-config: Setting 'basename_list=readme, 00readme' from built-in defaults.
texdoc debug-config: Setting 'ext_list=pdf, htm, html, txt, ps, dvi, ' from built-in defaults.
texdoc debug-config: Setting 'mode=view' from built-in defaults.
texdoc debug-config: Setting 'max_lines=20' from built-in defaults.
texdoc debug-config: Setting 'verbosity_level=2' from built-in defaults.
texdoc debug-config: Setting 'machine_switch=false' from built-in defaults.
texdoc debug-config: Setting 'badbasename_list=readme, 00readme' from built-in defaults.
texdoc debug-config: Setting 'interact_switch=true' from built-in defaults.
texdoc debug-config: Setting 'rm_dir=rmdir' from built-in defaults.
texdoc debug-config: Setting 'rm_file=rm -f' from built-in defaults.
texdoc debug-files: Configuration files are:
texdoc debug-files: active  /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/texdoc/texdoc.cnf
texdoc debug-texdocs: texdocs[8] = /home/alexey/.texlive2017/texmf-config/doc (index_mandatory=false, recursion_allowed=true)
texdoc debug-texdocs: texdocs[7] = /home/alexey/.texlive2017/texmf-var/doc (index_mandatory=false, recursion_allowed=true)
texdoc debug-texdocs: texdocs[6] = /home/alexey/texmf/doc (index_mandatory=false, recursion_allowed=true)
texdoc debug-texdocs: texdocs[5] = /usr/local/share/texmf/doc (index_mandatory=true, recursion_allowed=true)
texdoc debug-texdocs: texdocs[4] = /etc/texmf/doc (index_mandatory=false, recursion_allowed=true)
texdoc debug-texdocs: texdocs[3] = /var/lib/texmf/doc (index_mandatory=true, recursion_allowed=true)
texdoc debug-texdocs: texdocs[2] = /usr/share/texmf/doc (index_mandatory=true, recursion_allowed=true)
texdoc debug-texdocs: texdocs[2] using index: /usr/share/texmf (shift=doc/)
texdoc debug-texdocs: texdocs[1] = /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/doc (index_mandatory=true, recursion_allowed=true)
texdoc debug-texdocs: texdocs[1] using index: /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist (shift=doc/)
texdoc debug-tlpdb: Using shipped tlpdb data.
Sorry, no documentation found for algorithmicx.
If you are unsure about the name, try searching CTAN's TeX catalogue at
http://ctan.org/search.html#byDescription.
```

It feels as if some database needed to be rebuilt, but i didn't find any instructions.

What can i do to repair `texdoc`?

Comment: I noticed that when I upgraded from TL2016 to TL2017, algorithmicx dropped off the installation (I always do a full install of TeXLive) but the [`algorithmicx` listing on CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx) shows it as being contained in TeXLive, so I'm not sure what's happened.

Comment: Can you send the output of `texdoc -d algorithmicx`?

Comment: I have the same problem. And it is not specific to any package, texdoc cannot find anything.

Comment: Output is here: https://gist.github.com/ilyapopov/2bbdc4a3503b22f74927e24ef10dbd0c

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's [a bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/texlive-base/+bug/1817785) about this open for almost 2 years in Ubuntu's bug tracker. The report's author suggests this alternative solution to update the documentation database, which I tested and seems to work:

```
# dpkg-reconfigure texlive-base
```

Answer (score 5):

To find documentation files, `texdoc` uses a variety of strategies, depending on the type of TeX Live installation (vanilla or apt packages), among other things. For non-vanilla installations, the Lua function `kpse.find_file()` is used, which is an interface for `kpathsea`, which is the LaTeX utility for locating files in the directory tree.

To check if the problem is caused by `kpathsea`, you can try `kpsewhich -format "TeX system documentation" algorithmicx.pdf` in the terminal. If that doesn't give any results, then the `kpathsea` database is out of date. It can be updated with `sudo mktexlsr [path]`, in this case `sudo mktexlsr /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist` (see also [texdoc doesn’t search at $TEXMFHOME](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46003/texdoc-doesn-t-search-at-texmfhome)). After that, `kpsewhich` should be able to find the file, and consequently also `texdoc` should find it.

Note that it would be easier if `apt` made the call to `mktexlsr` for documentation packages, which apparently did not happen during the upgrade.

*Disclaimer:* I had the same problem as the OP and the above solution worked for me - however the search strategy of `texdoc` is rather complicated and the error may be somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

I installed the `texlive-latex-extra` package and later the `texlive-latex-extra-doc` package (using Ubuntu 18.04's apt utility). Similarly to the OP, `texdoc` failed to find documentation for most of the installed packages. I followed [Marijn's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/452630/201662) and this did the trick. Specifically, I issued the following command:

```
$ sudo mktexlsr /usr/share/doc/texlive-doc
```

This should work for those installing TeX Live through apt on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: In the linked answer there is another directory used. What is the difference between that directory and yours? Did you test the linked answer?  Result? Please do not answer the same answer twice  (see tex.stackexchange.com/a/517076/16550)!

Comment: @Mensch I did try the linked answer and it did not work. The path I give is the directory where documentation gets installed when you issue `sudo apt install texlive-latex-extra-doc`.