# Texdoc with MikTeX isn't working on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: miktex, ubuntu, texdoc

I'm using `MikTex` 4.2.1 on `Ubuntu` 20.04. When I tried to texdoc ctex, it displayed the following errors:

> Info: Running Texdoc not installed in the current TEXMFMAIN.
> /usr/bin/texdoc:41: module 'texdoclib' not found:
> no field package.preload['texdoclib']
> [kpse lua searcher] file not found: 'texdoclib'
> [kpse C searcher] file not found: 'texdoclib'

I'm new to Ubuntu and couldn't figure it out.

Comment: OP answered that the suggested duplicate doesn't answer their question, but didn't provide any details.  I would opine that anyone coming to this page should instead go to the proposed duplicate which has some possible fixes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to post a comment, but you may want to look at this other answer:

[texdoc does not work anymore after Ubuntu upgrade](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/431244/texdoc-does-not-work-anymore-after-ubuntu-upgrade)

Comment: No, it doesn't work also, and I have given up using texdoc command. I can find the help documentation on https://ctan.org/